# Confluent-platform control center issues using docker on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I am trying to set up confluent platform for my own use using their [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/6.2.0-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml). Running inside of an EC2.

The issue is when using the **control-center** in the browser. When trying to read messages in a topic it gives the error `an unknown error has occured. Check connection string.`

The control center is being accessed through an Nginx proxy. The other functionality seems to be working. Also I can produce/consume from topics using kafkacat.

In the docker-compose.yml the changes I have made are

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,**PLAINTEXT_HOST://my-ec2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092**
```

&

```
CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_URL: "http://my-ec2:8088"
CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://my-ec2:8088"
CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://my-ec2:8081"
```

Based off of this [thread](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/3374)

The error in the web browser console is a **404** for `wss://my-ec2.compute.amazonaws.com/ws/3.0/fmkjJPD2T7meVibQKUo_0A/consumer?srClusterId=3ae7391e62e5b78c329831768219f53b15d80aca&topic=test`

Ports 8081,8088,9021 and 80/443 are open.

Any idea which networking setting is incorrect?

**EDIT:** I might not have been clear, but all of the containers in the above docker-compose.yml are running inside of an EC2. I am connecting to the Control Center over HTTP. I have exposed the broker publicly also so that I can publish and consume to/from topics from outside of AWS.

I am also using KSQL, which is why the connection string for that was changed, so that it would work in the browser outside of AWS.

Creating topics and streams works correctly. However viewing messages or querying streams gives the error `An unknown error has occurred. Check the connection settings`.

The default connecting strings work fine if running the containers on my machine, as expected. They do not work correctly when running on an EC2 and accessing the control center from an external web browser.

I'm trying to find the correct network settings to allow the containers to connect to each other correctly, as well as for everything in the control center GUI to work correctly.

**EDIT 2/3/4:  Nginx config**

```
server {
    listen 80 ssl;
    listen [::]:80 ssl;
    
        location / {
                    auth_basic "Restricted";
                    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:9021;
      }
    
    }
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
    }

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location / {
                    auth_basic "Restricted";
                    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:9021;
        }
        location /ws {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:8088;
                    proxy_http_version          1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to connect control center to confluent cloud, you should not be using any container other than that one, so therefore you shouldn't even have `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`

Comment: Otherwise, if you are trying to run everything locally in Docker, you shouldnt need to edit any properties. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html# + That thread was only referring to KSQL, not the topic websocket browser

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm not trying to connect to confluent cloud sorry. I use that at work but wanted to set up my own kafka set up on an EC2 for my own use. I added an edit to better explain. Essentially all the images in the docker-compose.yml are running on an EC2. I want to be able to use the Control-Center GUI with all functionality from an external web browser. With the broker externally accessible also(this part works).

Comment: Got it. 1} control center and other components should be using `broker:29092` to communicate with Kafka,, so since you're not exposing port 9092, I'd say remove that listener. 2) Can you share the nginx config? The websocket on port 443 is your error for the UI. If you're not exposing that port outside the container, that explains the problem 3) change everything back except for `CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL` (notice the name changed in the file compared to the discussion in the thread)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Added the nginx conf. Well I will be sending messages from external producers to the cluster, which is why I have a listener on `:9092`. 

Port 443 does work for accessing from the browser. I am currently using a self signed cert on the url since I haven't purchased a domain. Could that cause issues?

Comment: I doubt the cert is the issue since you would get a something other than a 404 in that case. Seems you are terminating the HTTPS connection at nginx for port `:443->90921`, but you're missing `location /ws` for forwarding the websocket connection on nginx `:443`  to `wss://localhost`

Comment: @OneCricketeer So Nginx can't have a `:wss/` url prefix apparently. I updated the nginx config above. That is how the docs say to handle websockets in reverse proxies. Does that look correct to you?

Comment: Oh, I don't really know much about Nginx configs... However, I don't think the websocket is for KSQL, it's only for the Control Center server to your browser, so 1) port 8088 is not what should be used for `proxy_pass` 2) It's a websocket, not an HTTP connection, so you might want something completely different 3) and you'd want `443:443` forwarded on the control-center container

Comment: @OneCricketeer They are a dark art. I checked the requests in the fully local setup and youre right, for topic messages the request is to port `:9021` . I managed to fix the nginx config above. Websocket requests now work, and the I can view and produce messages in the GUI.

Weirdly it will still throw `an unknown error has occured. Check connection string` after the page has been open for a while, doesn't seem to be an error.

The KSQL control center messages do go through `:8088` instead of `:9021` so I'll try add that to my Nginx config too.

Comment: KSQL queries seems to be failing due to invalid cert on `:8088`, which makes sense since `wss` uses SSL. Oddly creating Streams/Tables works fine but that must go through the control center directly.

Comment: Yeah, the queries ought to be sent over HTTP. Only the records are returned back over a websocket / SSE

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can;t get the queries working for KSQL in the control center.  The request isn't going through nginx, it's going directly to the KSQL server. I think SSL is why it;'s failing. Is there a workaround do you think or will I have to buy a domain and proper cert?

Comment: I'm not very well-versed in SSL/certs, and don't really use Control Center, either. I'd suggest reaching out to Confluent Support directly.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Okay, thanks for all the help!